# Resampling Sentinel-1 to Landsat 8 size and location

Tags: python, rasterio, sentinel-1

I am training a convolutional neural network to classify landcover and I would like to ingest both Landsat 8 and Sentinel-1 into my classifier.

Currently it is working reasonably well for Landsat 8 but I want to get Sentinel-1 data, ideally at the same resolution and pixel locations. Is there any library that already does this or can you think of a good approach ? I'm using `rasterio` in python for most of my raster processing.

I'm downloading my Sentinel-1 data from Sentinel-Hub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [rasterio's virtual warping](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/virtual-warping.html#normalizing-data-to-a-consistent-grid). You could e.g. take the higher resolution Sentinel-1 image as a template raster from which you get the "vrt_options" dictionary with a specified crs, transform, pixel width/height etc. Then use that to read in both the Sentinel-1 and Landsat images, rasterio warps them on the fly to the specified options (be aware that this forces resampling of the lower-res/different grid Landsat images).

Comment: This worked like a charm!

Comment: How is this different from just using rasterio reproject with the Sentinel-1 image as the destination raster?\ and Lansat 8 as the source one?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with the [snappy modules](https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/19300362/How+to+use+the+SNAP+API+from+Python) (libraries of [SNAP](http://step.esa.int/main/toolboxes/snap/)) you can use the [collocate](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/snappy-collocate-set-masterproduct/1595) module to resample Sentinel-1 onto the resolution of Landsat-8. But the S1 data is delivered as GRD product which means that it has to be geocoded first. In case of 30 m are sufficient, multi-lookig to 30 meters is also an option. Depends on how far pre-processed the Sentinel-1 products you use are.

An example for its use is given here: https://eodag.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/tuto_burnt_areas_snappy.html